# Angularjs fancy scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using [**Angular** directives for **Twitter Bootstrap**](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for my product. There are many directives available in that for UI but I am unable to find **Fancy scrollbar** UI anywhere.

[image: Fancy scrollbar capture]
Is there any directive build in angularjs for fancy scrollbar. Please suggest.

Comment: And what is "fancy scroll"?

Comment: I am Sorry. It's SCROLLBAR. I have edited my question. Please see the image. Check this http://jquery-custom-scrollbar.rocketmind.pl/basic.html for what actually I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this post is a bit old and I guess it won't help you, but someone might find it useful. 
I just released a new directive that does exactly what you were looking for, 
It's a pure AngularJS scroll bar with no jquery dependencies.

https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [angular-perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/itsdrewmiller/angular-perfect-scrollbar). It's angular directive for [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need without the dependency of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a "fancy scrollbar" built into Angular Bootstrap.

I am not aware of any other options.

You could build your own :

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

You are going to run into a lot of cross browser compatibility issues though since styling controls like that is problematic at best.